# How to add an arc4random when the score is increment?

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, arc4random

I am making a game in which there are enemies of diferente colors, I want to do that if you get to a certain score a new enemy of different color is added to the game.

how can I add another color to my arc4random func when the score is 20?(20 for example)

class GameScene: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate {

```
var circuloPrincipal = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "circulo")

var enemigoTimer = NSTimer()

var hits = 0

var colorAmarillo: UIColor = UIColor(red: 0.9, green: 0.7, blue: 0.2, alpha: 0.9)

var colorAzul = UIColor(red: 0.1, green: 0.4, blue: 0.5, alpha: 1.0)

var colorVerde: UIColor = UIColor(red: 0.3, green: 0.7, blue: 0.5, alpha: 0.9)

var scoreLabel = SKLabelNode(fontNamed: "STHeitiJ-Medium")

 var score = 0

  //colorAmarillo = Yellow color
    //colorAzul = Blue color
    //colorVerde = Green color
```

func colisionPrincipal(enemigo: SKSpriteNode) {

//This is when the enemy makes contact with the player

```
        if hits < 3 && circuloPrincipal.color != enemigo.color{


            circuloPrincipal.runAction(SKAction.scaleBy(1.5, duration:0.5))




           enemigo.removeFromParent()

        hits++


            }

            if scoreLabel == "20" {


                //Here I want to add an enemy of another color


            }




        scoreLabel.removeAllActions()


        }else if circuloPrincipal.color == enemigo.color {

    //circuloPrincipal = player
    //enemigo = enemy
    //color = color


            enemigo.removeFromParent()

       score++

            scoreLabel.text = "\(score)"

        }
```

func enemigos()  //This función is the arc4random to random the colors 
          {

```
    let enemigo = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "circulo")
    enemigo.size = CGSize(width: 25, height: 25)
    enemigo.color = UIColor(red: 0.2, green: 0.2, blue: 0.2, alpha: 1.0)
    enemigo.colorBlendFactor = 1.0
    enemigo.zPosition = 1.0

            enemigo.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: enemigo.size.height / 2)
    enemigo.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = physicsCategory.enemigo
    enemigo.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = physicsCategory.circuloPrincipal
    enemigo.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = physicsCategory.circuloPrincipal
    enemigo.physicsBody?.dynamic = true
   enemigo.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = true


    enemigo.name = "enemigo"



    }

    let colorRandom = arc4random() % 3

    switch colorRandom {
    case 0:

        enemigo.color = colorAmarillo
        enemigo.colorBlendFactor = 1.0




        break

    case 1:

        enemigo.color = colorAzul
        enemigo.colorBlendFactor = 1.0


    break

    case 2:

        enemigo.color = colorVerde
        enemigo.colorBlendFactor = 1.0


        break
    default:


        break



    }
```

Comment: And what is your question, exactly?

Comment: how can I add another color to my arc4random func when the score is 20?(20 for example)

Comment: format your code, please... arc4random is not your function, and this statement seems unrelated to "when the score is 20". It seems that you want to add a new enemy when the score reaches 20, is that right? What is the problem with color?

Comment: yes, there is no problem with the color, I just want to spawn a new enemy of different color when the score is 20

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code and question is really messed up but maybe (just maybe) I will help you:)

First add import statement

```
import GameplayKit
```

Next - generate random enemy color

```
let colors = [SKColor.redColor(), SKColor.blueColor(), SKColor.greenColor()]

let randomColorIndex = GKRandomDistribution(lowestValue: 0, highestValue: colors.count - 1).nextInt()

// First solution using ternary conditional operator
enemy.color = score == 20 ? SKColor.blackColor() : colors[randomColorIndex]

// Second - using if-else clause
if score == 20 {
    enemy.color = SKColor.blackColor()
} else if score == 100 {
    enemy.color = SKColor.whiteColor()
} else {
    enemy.color = colors[randomColorIndex]
}
```

Comment: mikem, And what do I do with my arc4Random? because the colors of the the GKRandomDistributions dont work.

Comment: Code above works - did you changed enemy's colorBlendFactor property to 1? If you want get random color from array using arc4random - colors[Int(arc4random() % 3)]

Comment: it worked!!! but the only problem is that when the score is 20 it spawn only 1 enemy of blackt color. How can I make to continue spawning?

Comment: I found the solution!

Comment: :D If you want only enemies of black color after player achieved 20 points fix first line of condition: if score >= 20. If you want multiple enemies of black color to be spawned at once create a loop(for-in or while). And if you want to chose from all colors (including black) after player achieved 20 points - add black color to colors array if score is equal to 20 (this should be done only once!) and than set enemy color with this: enemy.color = colors[Int(arc4random() % 4)].

Comment: mikem, and what could I do if i want to add the black color when the score is 20 but keep spawning the other colors, and when the score is 30 add another color but keep spawning the other colors too?                                           BTW, thanks for your help, you are awsome

Comment: You want this? if score == 20 { colors.append(SKColor.blackColor()) } else if score == 30 { colors.append(SKColor.whiteColor()) }

Comment: var colors = [colorAzul, colorVerde]
            
            let randomColorIndex = GKRandomDistribution(lowestValue: 0,        highestValue: colors.count - 1).nextInt()
        
       
        
        

            if score == 20 { colors.append(SKColor.blackColor())
            
            } else if score == 30 { colors.append(SKColor.whiteColor())
            
           
            }else {
            enemigo.color = colors[randomColorIndex]
        }

Comment: I was wondering if I cold make something like "greater than until" Is that possible?

Comment: If you want keep colors array in one block with choosing color for the enemy: var colors = [colorAzul, colorVerde] 

if score >= 20 { 
  colors.append(SKColor.blackColor()) 
} 

if score >= 30 { 
  colors.append(SKColor.whiteColor()) 
}

let randomColorIndex = GKRandomDistribution(lowestValue: 0, highestValue: colors.count - 1).nextInt() 

enemigo.color = colors[randomColorIndex]

Comment: hey mikem, I want to thanks you for all your help, you where the onlyone that helped me on my problem, I know i didnt explain well my problem, but I am new at coding and sorry for my english too. btw it worked!!